# How to derive the formula for Expansion Factor Y in compressible flow?

Tags: compressible-flow, thermal-expansion

I tried to understand of some formulas in ISA Standard "Flow Equations for Sizing Control Valves":
http://integrated.cc/cse/ISA_750101_SPBd.pdf

ISA standard likes to give formulas without giving reasons. For example, following formula is about expansion factor Y (page 22, Eq.32) :

$$
Y = 1- \frac{x}{3F_{\gamma}x_T}
$$

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure above formula out, but without success.
I would be very grateful if someone could give a derivation, or you could point me to a literature.

Comment: Dimensional analysis is one possibility see BReynolds and Buckingham. Or it may derive from experimental work.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: So with valves, or what can be assumed to be orifices, how do you get the coefficient of discharge? As you "don't think so" ?? I remember "proving" those coefficients by experiment as labs at uni...

Comment: Dear Mike, You may be right, I find Buckingham's old paper, maybe it has answer. Thank you!